# Were there any elections under the Vichy regime?

Tags: world-war-two, france, election

My question is as in the title: during the [Vichy regime in France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vichy_France), from July 1940 to, say, June 1944 were there any official election of any kind - for mayors, lawmakers, etc? If none, do you have a reference? If yes, what were they for, how were they organized, and who got elected?

(I was not able to find any information on this question on google)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As per the [decree law of 16 November 1940](https://books.google.com.ph/books?redir_esc=y&id=DiJnAAAAMAAJ&focus=searchwithinvolume&q=election), elections were only allowed for the "smallest communes".

[This law was published](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1947858?read-now=1&refreqid=excelsior%3Aeeb21355d48b45ea801a3b7adfd9b245&seq=7#page_scan_tab_contents) in the Journal Officiel 12 December 12, 1940 and

> ...provided for the abolition of elected councils in communes and
>   municipalities of 2,000 population and over....It is now provided that
>   the members of councils in towns with a population from 2,000 to
>   10,000 shall be appointed by prefects, while in cities of over 10,000
>   the councillors shall be named by the minister of the interior.
>   **Communities of under 2,000 inhabitants may continue to elect their
>   councils as long as these bodies refrain from participating in
>   "politics."**

***(my emphasis)***

Also, the [Labour Charter of October 1941](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=bNkGDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=vichy%20labour%20charter&source=bl&ots=QyHKUopZSU&sig=XbQLd6RX8tD9pj-s-kRr9OZfkOs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi93Lr73I_fAhXFa94KHceoBOMQ6AEwD3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=vichy%20labour%20charter&f=false) allowed for elections of workers to newly set up *comites sociaux*. These committees were to plan "[social and welfare programmes ... and arbitrate in matters of training, wages and manpower](https://digital.library.adelaide.edu.au/dspace/bitstream/2440/61493/2/02whole.pdf)" (pdf) but they were, in reality, powerless and considered "[mere window-dressing](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=bNkGDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA99&lpg=PA99&dq=vichy%20labour%20charter&source=bl&ots=QyHKUopZSU&sig=XbQLd6RX8tD9pj-s-kRr9OZfkOs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi93Lr73I_fAhXFa94KHceoBOMQ6AEwD3oECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=vichy%20labour%20charter&f=false)".

In practice, the Vichy regime was an authoritarian state in which all positions of any significance were by appointment. The [regime rejected](https://books.google.com.ph/books?redir_esc=y&id=2GfyeutpUosC&q=election#v=snippet&q=election&f=false)

> the partisan strife of political parties

and

> "the pettiness of politics".

which were seen as weaknesses of the [Third Republic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_Third_Republic) (1870-1940). Thus, in a [speech on the 12th of August, 1941](http://www.ibiblio.org/pha/policy/1941/1941-08-12a.html), Petain stated

> Activity of political parties and groups of political origin is
>   suspended until further notice in the unoccupied zone. These parties
>   may no longer hold either public or private meetings. They must cease
>   any distribution of tracts or notices.

Comment: Thank you. I think that's fully answer my question.